# How to create a bigram from a text file with frequency count in Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, n-gram

I want to take a text file and create a bigram of all words not separated by a dot ".", removing any special characters. I'm trying to do this using Spark and Scala.

This text:

Hello my Friend. How are
you today? bye my friend.

Should produce the following:

hello my, 1
my friend, 2
how are, 1
you today, 1
today bye, 1
bye my, 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For each of the lines in the RDD, start by splitting based on `'.'`. Then tokenize each of the resulting substrings by splitting on `' '`. Once tokenized, remove special characters with `replaceAll` and convert to lowercase. Each of these sublists can be converted with `sliding` to an iterator of string arrays containing bigrams.

Then, after flattening and converting the bigram arrays to strings with `mkString` as requested, get a count for each one with `groupBy` and `mapValues`.

Finally flatten, reduce, and collect the (bigram, count) tuples from the RDD.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array("Hello my Friend. How are",
                               "you today? bye my friend."))

rdd.map{ 

    // Split each line into substrings by periods
    _.split('.').map{ substrings =>

        // Trim substrings and then tokenize on spaces
        substrings.trim.split(' ').

        // Remove non-alphanumeric characters, using Shyamendra's
        // clean replacement technique, and convert to lowercase
        map{_.replaceAll("""\W""", "").toLowerCase()}.

        // Find bigrams
        sliding(2)
    }.

    // Flatten, and map the bigrams to concatenated strings
    flatMap{identity}.map{_.mkString(" ")}.

    // Group the bigrams and count their frequency
    groupBy{identity}.mapValues{_.size}

}.

// Reduce to get a global count, then collect
flatMap{identity}.reduceByKey(_+_).collect.

// Format and print
foreach{x=> println(x._1 + ", " + x._2)}

you today, 1
hello my, 1
my friend, 2
how are, 1
bye my, 1
today bye, 1
```

Comment: Thanks @ohruunuruus. When I try to output this to a file I get: '[Ljava.lang.String;@7358dbec
[Ljava.lang.String;@4ece9e1d
[Ljava.lang.String;@6f124cb
[Ljava.lang.String;@41a68efc
[Ljava.lang.String;@1df56410
[Ljava.lang.String;@5800bbcf
[Ljava.lang.String;@7ddb1518
[Ljava.lang.String;@3a461b35   '              Any pointers?

Comment: @oscarm I've got a workaround for that now, though I'm not certain this is the best way to do it

Comment: would be easy to just concatenate the pairs?

Comment: I'm trying to run it, but I get this error:                                                                               [error]  found   : Array[String] => Array[String]
[error]  required: Array[String] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
[error]         _.trim.split(' ').sliding(2).flatMap(identity).map{_.mkString(" ")}

Comment: We can [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75563/discussion-between-ohruunuruus-and-oscarm) if you're interested.

Comment: @oscarm Not sure if you're still working on this, but I believe all the kinks are worked out now

Answer (score 2):

In order to separate entire words from any punctuation marks consider for instance

```
val words = text.split("\\W+")
```

which delivers in this case

```
Array[String] = Array(Hello, my, Friend, How, are, you, today, bye, my, friend)
```

Pairing words into tuples proves more inlined with the concept of a bigram, thus consider for instance

```
for( Array(a,b,_*) <- words.sliding(2).toArray ) 
yield (a.toLowerCase(), b.toLowerCase())
```

which yields

```
Array((hello,my), (my,friend), (friend,How), (how,are), 
      (are,you), (you,today), (today,bye), (bye,my), (my,friend))
```

The answer by ohruunuruus conveys otherwise a concise approach.

Comment: Nice work on the split, though this will create a bigram for "friend how" which OP doesn't want. You're totally right about bigrams and tuples.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Spark:

```
def bigramsInString(s: String): Array[((String, String), Int)] = { 

    s.split("""\.""")                        // split on .
     .map(_.split(" ")                       // split on space
           .filter(_.nonEmpty)               // remove empty string
           .map(_.replaceAll("""\W""", "")   // remove special chars
                 .toLowerCase)
           .filter(_.nonEmpty)                
           .sliding(2)                       // take continuous pairs
           .filter(_.size == 2)              // sliding can return partial
           .map{ case Array(a, b) => ((a, b), 1) })
     .flatMap(x => x)                         
}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array("Hello my Friend. How are",
                               "you today? bye my friend."))

rdd.map(bigramsInString)
   .flatMap(x => x)             
   .countByKey                   // get result in driver memory as Map
   .foreach{ case ((x, y), z) => println(s"${x} ${y}, ${z}") }

// my friend, 2
// how are, 1
// today bye, 1
// bye my, 1
// you today, 1
// hello my, 1
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@3b2c2ef (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
in the line: ".map{ case Array(a, b) => ((a, b), 1) })"

Comment: @oscarm I see. `sliding` returns partial list in the last array if there are less elements. Updated the answer.